# Creating a GUI for a C library in Python vs. C++

Tags: python, c, user-interface, tkinter

I have an C library that I compiled into an executable which takes in two required args (input file path and one option). I would like to create a GUI for it that will allow the users to choose the file path and the option from a drop down menu(for simplicity). The executable looks like this:

```
my_executable --file_location /path/to/file --read_mode ASCII
```

I have previously used Python's built-in TkInter library. Would it be possible to use Python's TkInter to run my C executable? I am looking for something simple like this for now:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Welcome to my software")
file_location = fd.askopenfilename()
```

Or should I start looking into GTK+ or QT in C++?

Comment: Sure, you can use Python to run an executable.

Comment: What the executable was written in isn't relevant, because you are just writing a wrapper that *executes* it, rather than *linking* to the original library.

Comment: The cost of starting the wrapper and using the GUI is, presumably, negligible compared to the work the executable itself does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need tkinter, you need tcl/tk - it was designed to be embedded in C programs. Tkinter itself embeds tcl/tk into python. You can avoid the overhead of embedding python and directly use tcl/tk.

For more information see [How to embed Tcl in C applications](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+to+embed+Tcl+in+C+applications) on the Tcl'ers Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) to create a simple GUI tool for your command line tool.

It all depends the way that you plan to pack and distribute your program. One of the advantages of tkinter is that it comes by default.

Once you have chosen your GUI toolkit, use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to attach your executable into the GUI program.